# GIT ignoring files in project/bin/debug folder except few files (Visual Studio Project)

Tags: vb.net, git, visual-studio, gitignore

This is how my .gitignore looks like:

```
# User-specific files
*.userprefs
!*.ini
!*.gitkeep
!*.bat

# Build results

[Bb]in/
[Dd]ebug/
```

What I want to achieve is to ignore all files in project/bin/debug but keep the files like *.ini *.bat and etc.

.gitignore is location in root folder:

```
rootfolder\project name\bin\Debug
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5534865/3676450) can help you.

Comment: Use gitignore's exclude `!` for the files required.

Comment: @nullpointer I already did. Can't you see my .gitignore file? i used `!`

Comment: @nullpointer you think I should modify

`[Bb]in/`
`[Dd]ebug/`

instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use `!` operator to negate pattern:

```
*.bat
!myfile.bat
```

In your case it's better to use .gitignore in specific directory. You should make .gitignore file in project/bin/debug with a content:

```
*.*
!*.bat
```

Or you can do it in your project main .gitignore:

```
MyFolder/*
!MyFolder/NotIgnored.txt
```

Without `*` it won't work.

Keep in mind that already staged files won't be ignored. You need to unstage them using `git rm --cached <file>`

Answer (score 1):

This works well for me. Add wildcard to your folders, and define the exceptions at the bottom.

```
# Build results    
[Bb]in/*
[Dd]ebug/*

# User-specific files
*.userprefs
!*.ini
!*.gitkeep
!*.bat
```

Comment: sorry but this adds all the files inside bin/debug.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by modifying the .gitignore of my root folder to:

```
# User-specific files
*.userprefs
!*.ini

# Build results
![Bb]in/
[Bb]in/*
![Dd]ebug/
```

Then creating another .gitignore file inside rootfolder/project/bin/debug/ directory with the ff:

```
*
!*.ini
!*.bat
```

Hope this can help someone in the future.

And btw, I got my .gitignore file from: https://www.gitignore.io/api/visualstudio